# Python - Create sparse matrix representation from 10000 random values

Tags: python, sparse-matrix

I'm having a homework assignment about airport flights, where at first i have to create the representation of a sparse matrix(i, j and values) for a 1000x1000 array from 10000 random numbers with the following criteria:

- i and j must be between 0-999 since are the rows and columns of array
- values must be between 1.0-5.0
- i must not be equal to j
- i and j must be present only once

The i is the departure airport, the j is the arrival airport and the values are the hours for the trip from i to j.

Then i have to find the roundtrips for an airport A with 2 to 8 maximum stops based on the criteria above. For example:

- A, D, F, G, A is a legal roundtrip with 4 stops
- A, D, F, D, A is not a legal roundtrip since the D is visited twice

NOTE: the problem must be solved purely with python built-in libraries. No external libraries are accepted like scipy and numpy.

I have tried to run a loop for 10000 numbers and assign to row, column and value a random number based on the above criteria but i guess this is not what the assignment asks me to do since the loop doesn't stop.

I guess the i and j are not the actual iloc and j representations of the sparse matrix but rather the values of those? i don't know.

I currently don't have a working code other than the example for the roundtrip implementation. Although will raise an error if the list is empty:

```py
dNext = {
    0: [],
    1: [4, 2, 0],
    2: [1, 4],
    3: [0],
    4: [3, 1]
}

def findRoundTrips(trip, n, trips):
    if (trip[0] == trip[-1]) and (1 < len(trip) <= n + 1):
        trips.append(trip.copy())
        return
    for x in dNext[trip[-1]]:
        if ((x not in trip[1:]) and (len(trip) < n)) or (x == trip[0]):
            trip.append(x)
            findRoundTrips(trip, n, trips)
            trip.pop()
```

Comment: I can't tell what your question is. I understand the homework but don't have a clear understanding of what you want help with.

Comment: yeah sorry about that. I'm trying to create the representation of a sparse matrix but i don't know how to do that without creating the 2D array, since it will be waste of time. How do i run a loop from 0 to 10000 and initialise the sparse matrix triplet(iloc, j and values) based on the criteria above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would build a sparse matrix:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import random

max_location = 1000
min_value = 1.0
max_value = 5.0

sparse_matrix = defaultdict(list)

num_entries = 10000
for _ in range(num_entries):
    source = random.randint(0, max_location)
    dest = random.randint(0, max_location)
    value = random.uniform(min_value, max_value)

    sparse_matrix[source].append((dest, value))
```

What this does is define a sparse matrix as a dictionary where the key of the dictionary is the starting point of a trip. The values of a key define everywhere you can fly to and how long it takes to fly there as a list of tuples.

Note, I didn't check that I'm using `randint` and `uniform` perfectly correctly, if you use this, you should look at the documentation of those functions to find out if there are any off-by-one errors in this solution.

Comment: thanks for the help, i just tested it and it seems to work. although this takes all possible values for the 10000 entries which means the source and destination have duplicates. if i only need the source and destination to be from 0-999 each i think the loop will run indefinitely since they can't go beyond the 999. That's what i'm trying to figure out now without any luck.

Comment: well my above assumption is wrong. Only the destinations will be duplicated.

Comment: Hmm? I'm not sure I understand. Does changing `max_location` from `1000` to `999` fix the problem? If not, do you think you can try explaining what's going wrong again? Also, if you find the answer helpful, don't forget to upvote. If it solves the problem, mark it as a solution.

Comment: The answer was very helpful indeed and there is nothing wrong with it. Sorry for my english is not my native language. What i'm trying to say is that when you store the destination values to the dictionary there will be duplicates since there is no check if the destination is already in the sparse_matrix[source]. But i guess it's easy to solve that. Thanks again man.